# ListPlot: Data is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica, I have a long list of data that I wanna plot, I have come across the function ListPlot but I get this error when I wanna plot. I have seen something about maybe trimming my data list down ?
But I don't know how to do that.

```
 data = {{5, 4.2180506341246474`*^-6}, {10, 
 8.52072632483756`*^-8}, {15,1.9122244963644555`*^-7}, {20, 
4.583863072516606`*^-8}, {25, 8.138004722270266`*^-9}, 
{30, 
1.5236067293781787`*^-9}, {35, 
1.9689607977818997`*^-8}, {40, 
1.0356015584142407`*^-9}, {45, 
5.1171329242687634`*^-9}, {50, 
1.3150023891748594`*^-9}, {55, 
2.75925031324734`*^-10}, {60, 
6.44739787013969`*^-10}, {65, 1.269501699841764`*^-9}, 
{70, 
 3.368354766378623`*^-11}, {75, 
 2.882696661780091`*^-11}, {80, 
 2.4182183464215087`*^-10}, {85, 
 3.982588451684898`*^-10}, {90, 
 6.737749787589035`*^-11}, {95, 
 8.116170964273532`*^-11}, {100, 
 6.030125496210169`*^-10}, {5, 
 2.1476267234440643`*^-6}, {10, 
 2.3244825805810026`*^-6}, {15, 
 1.376564833236655`*^-7}, {20, 
 2.972699644181631`*^-8}, {25, 
 4.737092876342727`*^-8}, {30, 
 8.191016754218927`*^-9}, {35, 
 8.898775290782262`*^-9}, {40, 
 6.666360149797248`*^-9}, {45, 
 7.417481547646882`*^-10}, {50, 
 1.739062622942222`*^-9}, {55, 
 4.842018315239307`*^-10}, {60, 
 6.521126861389932`*^-10}, {65, 
 1.3985827036122423`*^-9}, {70, 
 1.492147178019141`*^-10}, {75, 
 4.2134547161500933`*^-10}, {80, 
 6.831201201202558`*^-11}, {85, 
 1.0802444285398891`*^-10}, {90, 
 1.820839088556722`*^-11}, {95, 
 1.7132267011413344`*^-10}, {100, 
 3.754919516870398`*^-10}, {5, 
 0.00001044694319643655`}, {10, 
 5.69674157685483`*^-8}, {15, 8.315750786932738`*^-8}, 
 {20, 
 1.0019648005036426`*^-7}, {25, 
 5.5374731613526704`*^-8}, {30, 
 1.9485705516272266`*^-9}, {35, 
 1.0113888568168166`*^-8}, {40, 
 1.7883852014284595`*^-10}, {45, 
 1.3475441439488888`*^-9}, {50, 
 9.038105865797945`*^-9}, {55, 
 1.5816145773480966`*^-9}, {60, 
 9.346731416982425`*^-10}, {65, 
 1.9747183113229924`*^-10}, {70, 
 7.813851506825158`*^-10}, {75, 
 1.8343422005958098`*^-10}, {80, 
 2.432821218173799`*^-11}, {85, 
 4.1395116687213914`*^-10}, {90, 
 2.1055234143168004`*^-10}, {95, 
 7.072714932230835`*^-10}, {100, 
 1.0580839584733221`*^-10}, {5, 
 2.5798845260889457`*^-6}, {10, 
 2.3232081111840804`*^-7}, {15, 
 2.667892232508383`*^-7}, {20, 
 1.682870319735423`*^-7}, {25, 
 1.0484611243537326`*^-8}, {30, 
 5.680186101488732`*^-9}, {35, 
 4.835436533411094`*^-9}, {40, 
 4.3318993920735265`*^-10}, {45, 
 1.4476913311872237`*^-8}, {50, 
 1.8412321693611577`*^-9}, {55, 
 1.2250442659732012`*^-9}, {60, 
 1.2394579016661714`*^-9}, {65, 
 1.3640777227973738`*^-9}, {70, 
 2.233313125797408`*^-9}, {75, 
 2.0888533393477414`*^-10}, {80, 
 1.9447658506520675`*^-10}, {85, 
 1.3846095194972496`*^-10}, {90, 
 1.274324549282506`*^-10}, {95, 
 8.450766454310523`*^-12}, {100, 
 6.298694843322194`*^-10}, {5, 
 5.064138651648234`*^-6}, {10, 
 7.421893655109317`*^-8}, {15, 
 6.899580135924716`*^-8}, {20, 
 8.341725253025645`*^-9}, {25, 
 3.2432622035577643`*^-9}, {30, 
 9.402559699099224`*^-10}, {35, 
 6.667022356411859`*^-9}, {40, 
 1.3887713695363457`*^-8}, {45, 
 4.067975610974101`*^-9}, {50, 
 2.130756764244549`*^-9}, {55, 
 5.876054330139342`*^-10}, {60, 
 5.5580351570704426`*^-9}, {65, 
 1.1925382281657626`*^-11}, {70, 
 3.307998125545722`*^-10}, {75, 
 3.8655748988116185`*^-10}, {80, 
 1.0067273465424143`*^-11}, {85, 
 1.0708274713929411`*^-10}, {90, 
 3.8222332586554166`*^-10}, {95, 
 6.528819437769106`*^-11}, {100, 
 4.577643994791942`*^-10}, {5, 
 6.3069218582484736`*^-9}, {10, 
 3.496119937611541`*^-7}, {15, 
  1.5524046006115388`*^-7}, {20, 
 1.348710877120591`*^-7}, {25, 
 1.744500035260079`*^-8}, {30, 
 1.6603294248904193`*^-8}, {35, 
 2.5206405116488415`*^-8}, {40, 
  1.4639960586270222`*^-9}, {45, 
 5.5464045166870474`*^-9}, {50, 
 9.786485003821449`*^-9}, {55, 
 8.912516353001634`*^-10}, {60, 
 1.471096625592371`*^-9}, {65, 
 1.1946582824950649`*^-9}, {70, 
 1.986770813327404`*^-10}, {75, 
 8.73810462167828`*^-10}, {80, 
 1.481836574016208`*^-10}, {85, 
 1.9717731215993406`*^-10}, {90, 
 2.5542691844114277`*^-10}, {95, 
 1.870296630801057`*^-10}, {100, 
 4.8814658856710215`*^-11}, {5, 
 2.5900661319482445`*^-6}, {10, 
 1.0780841918704108`*^-7}, {15, 
 4.655536564862844`*^-8}, {20, 
 2.543054652487668`*^-8}, {25, 6.270341785015637`*^-9}, {30, 
 7.91889292098162`*^-9}, {35, 4.5637976602144815`*^-9}, {40, 
 8.356921214604936`*^-9}, {45, 1.6718361654608334`*^-8}, {50, 
 2.2999294061801205`*^-9}, {55, 1.6126339340916615`*^-9}, {60, 
 2.0568855673703833`*^-10}, {65, 6.052576150395791`*^-10}, {70, 
 5.877640181357158`*^-11}, {75, 4.6109719347766947`*^-10}, {80, 
 1.782630507857206`*^-11}, {85, 3.4094504242364744`*^-11}, {90, 
 2.1521641486957376`*^-11}, {95, 1.7693465429181382`*^-10}, {100, 
 1.108152605829104`*^-10}, {5, 3.1556932003850125`*^-6}, {10, 
 3.150971172099647`*^-7}, {15, 9.943829214376952`*^-8}, {20, 
 2.1072930805682054`*^-9}, {25, 7.871904774251177`*^-8}, {30, 
 1.6866458826162318`*^-8}, {35, 4.795657356481652`*^-9}, {40, 
 5.333511697714692`*^-10}, {45, 7.4482115262124705`*^-9}, {50, 
 2.867301230543851`*^-9}, {55, 1.718421442391107`*^-10}, {60, 
 9.530175559071542`*^-11}, {65, 8.064075761687711`*^-11}, {70, 
 1.0288790220335421`*^-9}, {75, 1.2003435795735374`*^-9}, {80, 
 1.0355412440290074`*^-9}, {85, 3.174113486780833`*^-10}, {90, 
 1.2641498504598634`*^-10}, {95, 7.976882480327851`*^-11}, {100, 
 1.5880932014212394`*^-11}, {5, 1.8876456584927902`*^-6}, {10, 
 5.712603557548288`*^-8}, {15, 1.0409753913422592`*^-8}, {20, 
 3.70525719392294`*^-9}, {25, 7.217910793655984`*^-9}, {30, 
 2.6859651963882603`*^-8}, {35, 1.7334341745842147`*^-8}, {40, 
 1.6478052352150378`*^-8}, {45, 8.832989797645319`*^-10}, {50, 
 5.2800718896975975`*^-9}, {55, 2.9356332556024264`*^-9}, {60, 
 8.311194232224003`*^-10}, {65, 2.3482950370701028`*^-9}, {70, 
 6.609181455148873`*^-10}, {75, 6.687310253639731`*^-10}, {80, 
 2.0450137423633253`*^-10}, {85, 1.8597772765870776`*^-13}, {90, 
 5.506236237381463`*^-11}, {95, 4.3327792764759966`*^-11}, {100, 
 1.7172396826556043`*^-10}, {5, 0.00003144088668999315`}, {10, 
 4.7345842694168693`*^-7}, {15, 5.046679805107057`*^-8}, {20, 
 4.2660259390362525`*^-8}, {25, 9.298404264634156`*^-9}, {30, 
 6.361737533444243`*^-9}, {35, 2.635880341166212`*^-8}, {40, 
 6.796773705779885`*^-9}, {45, 1.0889152233121153`*^-9}, {50, 
 6.683153680905807`*^-10}, {55, 1.197038904676683`*^-9}, {60, 
 4.953273024900673`*^-10}, {65, 2.7372783025689915`*^-9}, {70, 
 2.3236548538241373`*^-9}, {75, 9.319688689447546`*^-11}, {80, 
 1.8108111597248558`*^-10}, {85, 3.759319337869303`*^-10}, {90, 
 6.638019323373417`*^-11}, {95, 2.0068801250795827`*^-10}, {100, 
 3.103631692


p2 = ListPlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"meter", "W"}]
```

ListPlot: data is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers.

What could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data above is incomplete. It ends with `{100, 3.103631692`, the list is not correctly terminated. If you end the list at the previous value `, {95, 2.0068801250795827*^-10}}` then it plots correctly.

```
ListPlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"meter", "W"}]
```

[image]